# Why doesn't my Wailmer hatch with Aqua Ring?

Tags: pokemon-fourth-generation

I'm trying to breed a Wailmer with Aqua Ring that I will be EV training.  I have a female Wailmer and a male Goldeen that knows Aqua Ring, which is supposedly one of Wailmer's egg moves.  When the Wailmer hatches, though, it only knows Splash and Water Pulse (another egg move from Goldeen).

Why wouldn't he know Aqua Ring?

When I tried something similar with a Misdreavus and a Gastly, the new Misdreavus knew both Shadow Ball and Destiny Bond (and even other moves from the Gastly), so they can definitely inherit more than one move.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be because your version doesn't have this egg move. With the new games in each generation (first Platinum, then HG/SS), new egg moves are added, but these will only work if you do the breeding in that cartridge.

According to a [quick search](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ds/960099-pokemon-heartgold-version/faqs/58988), Aqua Ring is only an egg move for Wailmer in HeartGold/SoulSilver. So, if you're doing this breeding experiment in Diamond/Pearl/Platinum, then it will not be passed on.